# "The final major anatomist was Galen, active in the 2nd century"?

Tags: grammar

I am reading a book at the moment, and I came across this sentence:

> "The final major anatomist was Galen, **active** in the 2nd century"

I am not sure if the word "active" is correct or not in this sense. And if it is correct, should it not be "The final major anatomist was Galen, who was active in the 2nd century"?

Comment: No. You don't need "who was" because it is implied in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final major anatomist was Galen, who was active in the 2nd century.

The sentence is correct grammatically.

The relative clause "who was active in the 2nd century" can be reduced by omitting the relative pronoun who + to be as follows:

The final major anatomist was Galen, active in the 2nd century.